# Stripe: How to update an invoice created from a subscription checkout session?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am creating a subscription from a Stripe checkout session. After a customer goes through the checkout session, an invoice is then created and triggers `invoice.created`. On this event, I have a webhook that is attempting to update the invoice, however, by the time it gets here, the invoice is already set to `finalized` and I cannot update it.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Stripe support and their recommendation (for our situation) is to give the subscription a trial period and then set the trial end to a few minutes from that point in time so that the invoice can go through each event properly.